# how to solve simultaneous equations with solve and with result without roots

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

Here is the code:

```
syms G1 G2 G3 M1 M2 M3 P1 P2 P3 D1 D2 D3
S = solve(0 == 0.9 * (20 - G1) - 0.012 * D3 * G1, ...
      0 == 0.9 * (20 - G2) - 0.012 * D1 * G2, ...
      0 == 0.9 * (20 - G3) - 0.012 * D2 * G3, ...
      0 == -0.0033 * M1 + 0.002 * G1, ...
      0 == -0.0033 * M2 + 0.002 * G2, ...
      0 == -0.0033 * M3 + 0.002 * G3, ...
      0 == 0.1 * M1 - 0.0033 * P1 + 2 * 0.5 * D1 - 2 * 0.025 * (P1 ^ 2), ...
      0 == 0.1 * M2 - 0.0033 * P2 + 2 * 0.5 * D2 - 2 * 0.025 * (P2 ^ 2), ...
      0 == 0.1 * M3 - 0.0033 * P3 + 2 * 0.5 * D3 - 2 * 0.025 * (P3 ^ 2), ...
      0 == -0.5 * D1 + 0.025 * (P1 ^ 2) + 0.9 * (20 - G2) - 0.012 * D1 * G2, ...
      0 == -0.5 * D2 + 0.025 * (P2 ^ 2) + 0.9 * (20 - G3) - 0.012 * D2 * G3, ...
      0 == -0.5 * D3 + 0.025 * (P3 ^ 2) + 0.9 * (20 - G1) - 0.012 * D3 * G1)
```

The problem is that I need real solution, but I have got answers with roots. How can I get real answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "real solution" you mean a numeric value instead of the exact root-of-polynomial form, there are [two options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/choose-symbolic-or-numeric-arithmetic.html) depending on how you intend on using the results:

1. [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html): this will evaluate the `RootOf` expressions, assuming there are no free parameters, and return a numeric output of class `double`.  While the output is now limited to double-precision, if your goal is to use the roots in computation and care about performance, this is the fastest option.
2. [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html): this will evaluate the `RootOf` expressions, assuming there are no free parameters, and return a Symbolic output of class `sym`.  While the output is now able to be approximated to varying degrees of accuracy at evaluation by calling [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) beforehand, there may be a large computational overhead in subsequent calculations due to its Symbolic nature.